# android animation translate slide_left_in does not move fromXDelate 0%

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, animation

layout.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_big_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageStartLogo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bigstartlogo" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textStartLogo1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageStartLogo"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/textLogoFirstWord"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textStartLogo2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textStartLogo1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/textLogoSecondWord"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textStartTop1Left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/textStartLogo2"
                android:text="@string/textStartTopLeft"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textStartTop1Right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/textStartLogo2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/textStartTopRight"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutStartMiddle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textStartTop1Right"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textStartMiddle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/textStartMiddle"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/bottomBorderDivider"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorStartDivider" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/layoutStartMiddle"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutLogin"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textStartLogin"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/textLogin"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/startLoginUnderline"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorStartDivider" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorStartDivider" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutSignup"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textStartSignup"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/textSignup"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/startSignupUnderline"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorStartDivider"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            <LinearLayout>
                .....
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/emailLayoutToToggle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_email24" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/hint_email"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

slide_out_left.xml animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

slide_out_right.xml animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

When i apply slide_out_left.xml animation to emailLayoutToggle, it
moves from the right side of the screen(as predicted) and then instead of move all the way to left,and disappear from the screen, it stops at arround 70% of the width of the screen. Why is this? Do you need any else code to preview? or Pictures? For me it looks like that toXDelta = 0% calucaltes wrong width or something like that, why would it stop in middle of screen+20%...

Comment: Please check that the Parent Layout of emailLayoutToggle Layout does not have any margins.
As the width of Parent Layout of an animated View is considered as base width. Hence in your case, it needs to be match parent.

Comment: @iMDroid yes it does have some margins, but that's not the problem, I have tryed to delete it,and set all margins to 0dp, still having this problem. animation on id = startLoginUnderline and id = startSignupUnderline works perfectly, except at this emailtogglelayout